# How can I access an Intranet whilst on a WiFi connection?

Tags: internet-explorer

I've got a device that is connected to a WiFi network. If I use Internet Explorer to try and access an Intranet site, using it's hostname (so using an address of `http://intranet/`)

I get an error displayed:

> We're having trouble displaying this page
>
> ---
>
> We're having trouble with the page you're trying to reach and can't open it at the moment.
>
> Try the following:
>
> - Refresh the page or try again later.

Looking at the web server access logs, it doesn't appear to be the case that the phone even attempted to connect.

If I try specifying the IP address, then the page loads fine.

What might be restricting Intranet addresses being reached by host name? could it be related to a lack of mobile reception (even though WiFi reception is good)?

Comment: can other devices (PC, tablet, etc) access the site?

Comment: @NeilTurner Yes, and DHCP is pushing out settings for DNS servers that resolve the hostname correctly for those PC/Mac clients

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Phone appears to have trouble with [non-fully qualified domain names (FQDN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) such as `http://intranet` or `http://server`.

When setting up any kind of server for local or internal use, it's best to use a FQDN. For example...

- `http://intranet.local`
- `http://pc1.server.local`